# Вычисление периметра для n-многоугольника в python

Tags: python

Ребят, помогите. Я написал программу для вычисления периметра 6-угольника. Как ее нужно переделать, чтобы она могла вычислять периметр любого n-угольника, где n вводить нужно с клавиатуры (при этом программа сама задает координаты точек). Как это можно сделать?

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "point(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")"


class hexagon:

    def __init__(self, A, B, C, D, E, F):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D
        self.E = E
        self.F = F

    def __str__(self):
        r = "hexagon(" + str(self.A) + "," + str(self.B) + "," + str(self.C) + "," + str(self.D) + "," + str(
            self.E) + "," + str(self.F) + ")"
        return r

    def sides(self):
        AB = ((self.B.x - self.A.x) ** 2 + (self.B.y - self.A.y) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
        BC = ((self.C.x - self.B.x) ** 2 + (self.C.y - self.B.y) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
        CD = ((self.D.x - self.C.x) ** 2 + (self.D.y - self.C.y) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
        DE = ((self.E.x - self.D.x) ** 2 + (self.E.y - self.D.y) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
        EF = ((self.F.x - self.E.x) ** 2 + (self.F.y - self.E.y) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
        FA = ((self.A.x - self.F.x) ** 2 + (self.A.y - self.F.y) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
        return AB, BC, CD, DE, EF, FA

    def perim(self):
        a, b, c, d, e, f = self.sides()
        return a + b + c + d + e + f


A = Point(0.0, 0.0)
B = Point(0.0, 3.0)
C = Point(4.0, 1.0)
D = Point(5.0, 1.0)
E = Point(6.0, 1.0)
F = Point(7.0, 2.0)
print(A.__str__(), B.__str__(), C.__str__(), D.__str__(), E.__str__(), F.__str__())
hx1 = hexagon(A, B, C, D, E, F)
print(hx1.__str__())
print(hx1.sides())
print(hx1.perim())
```

Comment: def __init__(self, *points)? А затем вычислять длины сторон по координатам концов отрезка.

Comment: Не нужно специально вызывать метод ``__str__()`` , он вызывается автоматически, когда нужно. ``print(A, B, C, D, E, F)`` делает то же самое, что и ваша монструозная строчка.

Answer (score 2):

Пробуйте, добавляйте нужные вам методы.

```
from math import sqrt

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Hexagon:
    def __init__(self, *points):
        self.points = list(points)

        self.sides = list()

        self.perim()

    def perim(self):
        self.perim = 0

        for i in range(len(self.points)):
            start = self.points[i - 1]
            end = self.points[i]

            side = sqrt((end.x - start.x)**2 + (end.y - start.y)**2)

            self.sides.append(side)

            self.perim += side


a = Point(0, 0)

b = Point(1, 1)

c = Point(2, 0)

ABC = Hexagon(a, b, c)

print(ABC.perim)
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу не кодом, а алгоритмом.

Чтобы рассчитать периметр N-многоугольника, нужны конструкции, позволяющие хранить любое кол-во элементов (в данном случае N). Для этого подойдут списки (`list`) и словари (`dict`).

Структура может быть следущей

```py
# list
points = []
points.add(Point(1,2)) # A
points.extend([Point(3,4), Point(5,6)]) # B, C и тд

# dict
points = {}
points['A'] = Point(1,2) # A
points.update(B=Point(3,4), C=Point(5,6)) # B, C, ...
```

Передавать в функцию/метод/класс можно в как объект

```
Hexagon(points) # list и dict
```

или как в соседнем ответе

```
Hexagon(*points) # list
Hexagon(**points) # dict
```

Через словарь удобнее, если нужно будет выводить информацию о длине стороны многоугольника

```
prev_key, prev_val = None, None
for name, point in self.points.items(): 
    if not prev_key:
        prev_key = name
        prev_val = point
        continue
    side = ....... # расчет растояния между point и prev_val
    print(f'{name}{prev_key} = {side}')
if prev_key:
    side = .......
    print(f'{name}{prev_key} = {side}')
```

Подробнее о способах передачи списков и словарей можно почитать, например, [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/482464/)